Coprimality of $\frac{(N \mathfrak{b})}{\mathfrak{b}}$ and $\frac{(N \mathfrak{c})}{\mathfrak{c}}$ when $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ are coprime.
Assume that $\mathfrak{b}$ is an integral ideal of ring of integers of a number field $K$ of $\mathfrak{o}_K$, then $N \mathfrak{b} \in \mathfrak{b}$ follows from lagrange's theorem. Hence $(N \mathfrak{b}) \subset \mathfrak{b}$. In a number field containment and divisibility are equivalent thus there exist an integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}_1$ such that $(N \mathfrak{b})=\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{b}_1$.
Now assume that $\mathfrak{c}$ is another integral ideal coprime to $\mathfrak{b}$, then there exists another integral ideal $\mathfrak{c}_1$ such that $(N \mathfrak{c})=\mathfrak{c}\mathfrak{c}_1$. Given that $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ are co-prime, can I conclude that $\mathfrak{b}_1$ and $\mathfrak{c}_1$ are coprime?
I do not think this is true, because even if $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ are coprime, that does not necessarily imply that $N \mathfrak{b}$ and $N \mathfrak{c}$ are coprime. But I am not able to find any such example. Can anyone suggest what can be done.

think about the case when  and  are prime ideals and contain the same prime number $p$

I doubt if there is a relation between the norm of an ideal, and a prime the ideal it consists

there is; the norm is $p^f$ where $f$ is the residual degree

I will assume you know some of the basic results concerning decomposition of ideals in a number field and the (absolute) ideal norm. Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n > 2$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $p$ a rational prime that splits completely in $K$. Let $\frak{p}_1$, $\frak{p}_2$ be distinct prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying above $p$. Then $N(\frak{p}_1)$$ = N(\frak{p}_2)$$ = p = \frak{p}_1\frak{p}_2\frak{q}_1 \dots \frak{q}$$_{n - 2}$, where the $\frak{q}$$_i$ are the other primes lying above $p$. Translating to your notation, we have $\frak{p}_1 = \frak{b}$, $\frak{p}_2 = \frak{c}$, $\frak{p}_2\frak{q}_1 \dots \frak{q}$$_{n - 2}$$=\frak{b}_1$, and $\frak{p}_1\frak{q}_1 \dots \frak{q}$$_{n - 2}$$=\frak{c}_1$, thus we have an example with $\frak{b}$, $\frak{c}$ coprime but $\frak{b}_1$, $\frak{c}_1$ not coprime, since $n > 2$.

I do not know much about decomposition of ideals in number field and ideal norm. Can you provide some good references.

There are many references. Some good books are Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory" or Marcus's "Number Fields." A free reference available online would be Andrew Sutherland's number theory course notes, which are available on his website. (FYI, this last reference develops the theory of ideal norms in much greater generality than is needed for this problem)

Will this hold in specific cases like $K$ is a field where $\mathfrak{O}_K$ is a principal ideal domain or when $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$
